# Temporarily stop intra site mailflow in Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Say I have two Exchange 2010 servers in two different sites, part of the same domain. All mail comes into site A and Exchange transports mail intended for mailboxes in Site B automagically.

How can I temporarily stop the flow from A to B with A queueing up the messages that are going to B so that I can release them again as soon as I've done what I need to do on site B?

I'd like site A to be unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Exchange for Site A:

In Exchange Management Console, select Toolbox and there start the Queue Viewer. The Queue Viewer is in Messagedeliverytools. Find the queue for Site B, select it and click on `Suspend` in the right pane.

When your work on Site B is done, you can just click on `Resume` here.

Comment: Does that also stop the invisible  “Intra Organization Send Connector”  ?

Comment: There are a couple of queue listed. One is Delivery Type "SMTP Relay to Remote Active Directory Site" and the other is Delivery Type "Shadow Redundancy". I assume the SMTP link is the one to pause?

Comment: The SMTP is the correct one yes.